ZipException while opening "jna-4.0.0.jar": Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size) Error. When running project with maven command
When ı run my test automation with "maven clean install" command, I get an error:
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error reading /Users/public/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.0.0/jna-4.0.0.jar; Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size)

I encountered no problems when I downloaded and ran the same project on a different computer. I deleted the C:/Users/public/.m2/repository file and ran it again, but it gave the same error.
is it an IDE-related problem? If not, what is the source of it.

First try to build on plain command line without IDE... also check if there are any WARNING's during the build...

It is an OpenJDK bug; see https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8313765
The bug report explains it like this:

The following ZipException may be thrown when the data contained in the CEN Extra fields are problematic:
Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size)

The ZipException may occur due to:

Some releases of Ant and commons-compress create CEN Zip64 extra headers with a size of 0 when Zip64 mode is required

fixed in Commons-compress 1.11 (2016) and Ant 1.10.14 (2023).


Extra field includes padding not included in the Extra data field headers
The BND tool added problematic data to the extra field

fixed in BND 5.3 (2021) and maven-bundle-plugin 5.1.5 which includes BND 5.3.




According to the report, this is fixed in Java 22, and backported to Java 11, 17 and 21.

The following are possible workarounds:

Update the Java installation you are using for your Maven builds to a version with the bug fix; see the bug report or release notes for the specific version details.
Rebuild the "jna-4.0.0.jar" file you are using from its source code1.
Find another version or build of the JNA jar file that doesn't have this problem.  (It looks like version 4.0.0 is pretty old ...)


1 - If you go down this route, make sure that you address the cause of the invalid CEN header; i.e. avoid using a buggy versions of Ant to build it.

Thank you for your answer. I solved the problem as follows. I deleted the jna-4.0.0.jar file under the m2 folder that you saw in the error and defined the 5.0.0 version in its place. I added the maven dependency to my project. The problem is solved.
<dependency>
<groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
<artifactId>jna</artifactId>
<version>5.13.0</version>
</dependency>

